# Difference between GraphDatabaseServer and BOLT in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying to start a new Java project in Neo4J, and going through some tutorials and examples I have seen two way to access Neo4j from Java. The GraphDatabaseServer class and the Bolt driver classes.

As I understand, the GraphDatabaseServer is prefered when you are deploying your application inside the Neo4j DB because it can directly access the underlying DB while the other can make it easy to access an external DB server. Is this correct? Are there any other differences, prefered use cases for one or the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two ways of accessing Neo4j via Java you refer to are embedded mode (Neo4j runs in the same JVM as your application), and remote server.

`GraphDatabaseService` is what gives you access to the embedded Neo4j instance and this is not available to you if your Neo4j instance runs in server mode. Plus, you cannot use this in a non-jvm language.

Bolt on the other hand, is a binary protocol and the preferred way of accessing a remote Neo4j server (instead of the earlier Http based one). Neo4j provides Bolt drivers in various languages. (http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/)